# Axios Problems (uncaught in promise) using zustand

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, zustand

Hi there i have problems with making the api call to my server. Using Postman i receive correctly my data from the URL but when i come into react and i use Axios to get those data i have the Axios error Uncaught in promise status code: 300 Here my code.

```
import {create} from 'zustand'
import axios from 'axios'

const URL1 = "http://localhost:5000/livespa"

export const useStore = create((set, get) => ({
    liveSpa:[],
    loadLivespa: async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(URL1)
      set({ liveSpa: await response.data})
    },
}))
```

And my frontend page is like

```
const LiveSpa = () => {
  const data = useStore((state) => state.liveSpa)
  const loadBets = useStore((state)=> state.loadLivespa)

  useEffect(() => {
    loadBets()
  }, [])

return (...)
}
```

I tried using Fetch but same problems, debugging my node server but it works fine using Postman

Comment: You solve this?